# Brownian motion a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian motion and $\tau$ a finite stopping time. Assuming that I know that $B(\tau)$ is a martingale, does this imply that $E(B(\tau))=0$ and $E((B(\tau))^2)=\tau$ just as one would have for $\tau=t$ and $t \in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Do you mean $E[(B(\tau))^2]$ or $(E[B(\tau)])^2$ ?  Is this supposed to be conditioned on $\tau$ or an expectation over the distribution of $\tau$?

Comment: @Henry clarified it. it is an expectation over both

Comment: I assume you actually mean the stopped process so $B(t\wedge \tau)$?

Comment: What do you meanby "$B(\tau)$ is a martingale"? $B(\tau)$ is a random variable, not a stochastic process. Do you mean "$(B(t \wedge \tau))_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale"?

Comment: Maybe this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515946/265240 will help you. More details can be found in Continuous time Markov processes by Liggett.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the stopping time $\tau:=\inf\{t: B(t)=1\}$. This time satisfies $\tau<\infty$ and $B(\tau)=1$ (both of these holding almost surely), so that $E(B(\tau))=1\not=0$.

Comment: how can you ensure that $\tau$ is finite?

Comment: By the reflection principle, $\Bbb P[ \tau>t] =\Bbb P[\max_{0\le s\le t} B(s)<1]=2\Phi(1/\sqrt{t})-1$, which tends to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. Therefore $\Bbb P[\tau=\infty]=0$.